# Horizontal scrollable thumbnail view with active text caption

Tags: jquery, html, iphone

I've put a group of images in a horizontal list view with scroll bar e.g

```
<li><span>image tile</span><img>image1</></li>
<li><span>image tile</span><img>image2</></li>
<li><span>image tile</span><img>image3</></li>
<li><span>image tile</span><img>image4</></li>
```

ect.. for an iPad which acts as an index page for the sliding pages.

What i'm trying to achieve is when scrolling horizontally along the thumbnails I would like to show is only one active caption showing at a time e.g the `<span>` when one of the thumbnails in the list is positioned center of the screen.

So imagine 9 thumbnails in a row and thumbnail 5 is in the center so its caption will be visible.

Hope it makes sense. Thanks in advance for any help and advice given

Comment: I follow what you are going for but you really need to put some effort into coding. Your probably going to need to also use jquery mobile http://api.jquerymobile.com as well. Gl. Hope I can help you once you have some code.